# SQL: select datetime values prior to that date based on it's value

Tags: sql

I want to select rows for a field MRD which is declared as date where it is prior for that date only.

So
(case when sum (transPoints) > 4 and MRD is that same date then 4

So if a row has a date of today, I want the case when to be triggered when the transaction points are bigger than 4 against all columns with the same date.

As you can imagine the date field will be different against many rows.

Comment: could you please post some example of data? your question is not that clear. the question is specific for any RDBMS?

Comment: maybe you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can understand from your question, it seems that the `GROUP BY` clause may be what you're looking for. If your date column is in the correct format then you may have to use something like:

```
SELECT CAST(DateColumn as DATE)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CAST(DateColumn as DATE)
```